# Shifting Math.ceil in Java

Tags: java, math, methods, rounding, ceil

I want to perform a ceiling function on a number (33.1504352455) so that it returns 33.16. When using ceiling, of course, it returns 34.0. How would I shift the character that the ceiling is acting on so that it returns 33.16?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better precision, always opt for BigDecimal. You could do it like:

```
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(33.1504352455);
b = b.setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING)
System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
number = Math.ceil(oldnumber * 100) / 100.0;
```

But this could be subject to the vagaries of floating point math.